# WebView on Lollipop won't work but it works on Kitkat

Tags: android, android-webview, android-5.0-lollipop

My WebView works fine on Kitkat and lower API levels, but on Lollipop my WebView is in an infinite loading state. How to fix it to work on Lollipop too?

This is error that is showing:

> E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus...
>   E/chromium: [ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(258)] Failed to init browser shader disk cache...
>   E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

Answer (score 0):

Well! Newer versions of android (5.0+, i guess) are using Updatable WebView

> The bad parts Of course, all of this is not of much use at the moment
>   because Android OS usage statistics look like this: Android usage
>   statistics
>
> And we still need to support older versions of Android in our hybrid
>   apps, sometimes all the way to Gingerbread. The situation will
>   probably change soon and this is really not that much of an issue in
>   the long run.
>
> But there's still the problem with Android fragmentation and many
>   different device manufacturers "improving" their own versions of
>   Android. They can (and probably will) change the WebView and adjust it
>   to their own needs. So I guess we'll keep on fighting WebView device
>   inconsistencies, but at least to a lesser extent.

https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/the-updateable-webview-on-android-5-lollipop-what-is-it-and-why-should-you-care